# Can Version Control System help me protecting my code?

Tags: svn, version-control

Can a Version control System(like Subversion) help me protecting my code?

I'd like to  hire outside freelance coders(or an outsourced team) to work on a web application project.

I'd like that outside coders working on the project should have access to only that part 
of the code on which they are working and not to the complete code.

This is to prevent code theft so that nobody can download the complete code or  the complete application.

Is something like this possible with the help of a VCS(like subversion)?

Comment: Thanks both of you Oded and Mchl

Answer (score 2):

In short, yes, it can.

What you will need to do is place the code you want to expose in a branch of its own, and give access to that branch only to the external developers.

You will have to make sure that they still have everything needed to compile and work with that bit of code however.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81361/how-to-setup-access-control-in-svn) SO question about access control in subversion.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to allow access to only specific branches.

See
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve.auth
for Subversion documentation on this subject