# SVN folder (not repository-wide) permissions

Tags: svn, permissions, hosting, repository

I am a bit new to SVNed code.

We are a small team (4 people) divided into two duos.
Each of the duos has its own disjoint share of the project.
I want to be able to SVN a project to a single repository with the following:

- each duo, should be able to **write to it's own** "section" of the rep'.
- each duo, should be able to ***read-only* the other** duo's section.

Can this be done on a single repository?
Are there folder-specific, rather than repository-wide permissions?
Is this hosting/repository service dependent? I am currently hosted at XP-Dev.

Would appreciate any kind of comment or reference.
David

Comment: Are you sure that you need access control for only 4 people. This sounds like over-engineering to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your best bet is to use Subversion's [path-based authorization](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html#svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz). This may be hosting-service dependent - you'll have to ask around at XP-Dev to find out if they support it.

An example would be something along the following lines:

```
[groups]
proj1-developers = harry, joe
proj2-developers = frank, sally

[proj1:/projects/proj1]
@proj1-developers = rw
@proj2-developers = r

[proj2:/projects/proj2]
@proj1-developers = r
@proj2-developers = rw
```

This can also be used in conjunction with Apache-based [per-directory access control](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.authz.perdir) (using the `AuthzSVNAccessFile` directive) and password-based access (using the `AuthUserFile` directive pointing at a file created using `htpasswd`). I'm currently using all three successfully, and also added on optional LDAP authentication. It helps when you have full access to the repository server.

Comment: SOLVED: Many thanks. I will check if Dev-XP support this, but this seems to be the method.
It all depends on whether they have a tiny boolean allowing path-based permissions or not. Many many thanks!

Comment: I've actually found a really good Stack-Overflow post: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81361/how-to-setup-access-control-in-svn

In addition, another nice site to look at: 
http://www.startupcto.com/server-tech/subversion/locking-a-branch-in-svn