# How to protect directory inside a SVN branch?

Tags: svn

Here is the situation - let's say I have a branch on SVN called Accounting. Inside of Accounting I have three folders named A, B and C. Is it possible to allow to some users to get content of all these folders but to disallow for others? For example I want to have a permission to manipulate with content of all these folders but some other person should just get access to the folder named A.

Comment: This might help :  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81361/how-to-setup-access-control-in-svn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at authz and path based authorization: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html

There are also commercial tools such as [Subversion Access Control](http://www.wandisco.com/subversion/accesscontrol) that provide a nice user interface to control access per user/group.

Answer (score 1):

go to conf folder and open authz file and set the users as one group to whom you want to give access permission