# How to set permissions in an svn repository?

Tags: svn, user-permissions, svnadmin

I created a repository on a network drive with `svnadmin create repos`.

Is there a way to set user permissions to the repository?

And if that is the case how can those permissions be set?

Comment: It seems to be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81361/how-to-setup-access-control-in-svn

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you need to manage access via `svn://` protocol (embedded authorization), all you need to do is to change files in `conf` folder of your newly created repository:

1. Set up passwd (`repos/conf/passwd`) in order to define a list of users and passwords
2. Set up authz (`repos/conf/authz`) in order to define groups and privileges
3. Set up svnserve.conf (`repos/conf/svnserve.conf`) in order to define general access configuration

Here is simple guide of [how to edit and configure access to your repository](http://wiki.wsmoak.net/cgi-bin/wiki.pl?Subversion/Configuration). Also you can consult [official documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve.auth) in order to dive into subversion access management.

In case you need to manage access via `http://` protocol, you might like to consult [official subversion documentation on this matter](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html), it's a bit more complex topic than embedded subversion authorization.

Comment: But doesn't this approach only work if the repository is on a server and not a network drive?

Comment: if you mean `file:///` protocol, then you're right, it does not work. Actually, there is no access management for `file:///` protocol available.

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question ^^

Comment: is there a faster way if you have 100 repos to point them all to the same auth and passdb ? i have it running with http:// but can't figure it out with svn://

Comment: @DanyKhalife You can have a single/global auth and passwd file but the svnserve.conf file in your 100 repos will need to be updated to point at the global auth and passwd file. You'd update `authz-db` and `password-db` in the svnserve.conf files.

Comment: thanks but actually the way i ended up doing this is by providing a conf file to svnserve during startup and that conf file specifies the authz-db and password-db files, no need to anything on a per repository basis