# How to connect to SVN from one Mac to another in same network?

Tags: xcode, macos, svn

I've set up a SVN repository on a Mac machine, let's say Mac1. On this machine, I can access it locally in xcode like this: file:///user/MyProject

I also did that to add users: 
[How to setup access control in SVN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81361/how-to-setup-access-control-in-svn)

Everything works on Mac1. 
Now, on Mac2, my co-worker's machine, he needs to connect to that repository on Mac1 too. What should I do?

Can I use file://192.168.10.xxx/user/MyProject or something similar? Do I have to set up a web server? (We don't really want the traffic go through http), 
Do I have to set up another different account information?

Thanks

Comment: You need to either create users on the machine hosting the repo and use `svn+ssh` or set up `svnserve` or set up `Apache/WebDAV` with svn.

Comment: I thought you couldn't establish access control when using the `file://` protocol :-?

Comment: Right. file://192.168.10.xxx/...does not work. It says the location is not reachable.

Comment: Start here: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.choosing.html

Comment: When you use file:/// access (note 3 slashes), there is no access control. Hook scripts will execute on the committer's workstation, not the server. This protocol is not meant for network/shared access. You need to install a Subversion server, such as CollabNet Edge or uberSVN (or you can roll your own, if you want).

Comment: Thanks. it is working now. The link from Deceze has everything I need. Thanks a lot.