# Tool to manage svn, git or cvs

Tags: git, svn, version-control

Is there any tool that allows me to do the following in at least one of these version control tools (svn, cvs or git)?
Let's imagine I've a team which is working on a repository. This repository has a lot of files. Is it possible to an administrator of the system to allow some users just to read (check out) a file and allow another one to change it (do the commit)?

If theres no tool for this, would it be interesting to develop it?

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking whether some users can be set up with read-only access to the repository and others can be set up with read-write access? If so, this is common with Subversion and very likely possible with CVS and Git too.

Comment: the read-only access is for files. I want some users to be able to change some files and other user to be able to change other files. But the files are all in the same repository.

Comment: You might find some answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81361/how-to-setup-access-control-in-svn

Comment: While there may not be one particular tool that will do this for all 3 VCS systems, I believe the effect can be achieved through *some* tool for each of them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While for `SVN|Git|<some SCM>` all possible ACLs work on directory level (not deeper), in both these systems are (and can be used) hooks, in which you can implement **any** needed commit-policy