# Read-only SVN user for SSH

Tags: svn, ssh

I searched on how to make read-only ssh user for SVN and couldn't find answer. 
To my understanding, I am not using SVNserve so cannot use its config file (as I suppose svnserve is only used in http:// or https:// method).

I connect to my SVN for checkout using this URL:
svn+ssh://domain.com/repos/project/

Can you please advise on how I can create a new user which has only readonly access to the repos?

I am using CentOS 7.2 (x64)

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to setup access control in SVN?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81361/how-to-setup-access-control-in-svn)

Comment: i TRIED this already but it was not working. I found out the reason. Reason is that each repository has its separate **svnserve.conf** and even if you start svnserve with this command _/usr/bin/svnserve -d -r /svn --config-file=/svn/svnserve.conf_ it just dont matter. It will still use the file that is in the each individual repository. So if you work on 10 projects you have to edit 10 svnserve in 10 repos