# Setup repository privilege in svn

Tags: svn

I have a subversion at this folder : http://202.45.139.85/svn/UAP_4.0/4.0.1

Now I'm creating a new folder for 4.0.2.

I already add in my username at file authz in folder /var/www/svn/uap/repo/conf

```
[aliases]
anirzam

[groups]
test = anirzam

[repository:/erynn]
@test = r
```

But, I still manage to check in file in this folder.

I have a list of username in file :
/etc/apache2/mods-enabled# vim dav_svn.passwd

```
anirzam:$apr1$vk/00Pnk$57Ss.H0pkoT7gKKoDNWCu/
```

My question:

Is it the correct way to control access for repository in svn?
And do I have to restart the svn once I edit the authz file then only it can get reflect?

FYI, I'm referring to this link [How to setup access control in SVN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81361/how-to-setup-access-control-in-svn).

Thank You.

Comment: What should be **different**? What do you mean by "check file"?

Comment: @NicoHaase check in file..

Comment: i want the folder only to be read only.

Comment: So, where's the rest of your configuration? Did you remove permissions for anonymous access?

Comment: rest of the configuration.. meaning?
for this case, i only modify 2 files : 
/var/www/svn/uap/repo/conf/authz --> to edit the repository to be read only
/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dav_svn.passwd--> to add the username and password

Comment: Well, as you are using Apache to serve Subversion access, there might be more configuration. And if there is no more configuration, I'd assume that you have not disabled anonymous access

Comment: I think it would be better if you also share your apache configuration file. By default apache configuration doesnt point to your configuration and password file. This will help to eliminate the possibility that the incorrect file is used for svn authorization.  This will also help to eliminate the possibility that probably some other form of authorization could be used hence your file you are modifying is not used at all.