# SVN - password protect each project in the repository

Tags: svn, passwords, repository

Hope everyone is healthy..

We have an svn repository, which is password-protected.
Our manager wants to have each project of the repository password-protected, not just the entire repository..I have done some research but haven' t found a solution to that..can anyone help?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Maybe this post can help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81361/how-do-i-set-up-access-control-in-svn

Comment: Thank you very much! That will be of help, I' ll try it out, thank you once again!