# Access Control with SVN on Apache/Linux 20.0

Tags: linux, apache, svn, ssh, access-control

We have Apache Subversion installed on an Apache 2 / Linux 20.0.... installed but the problem is when the repo is accessed via direct link:

E.g. domain.com/svn/repo

You can access all the files in there. Is there a way to control that via a password?

I have tried changing the svnserve.config, authz amd passwd to function as intended but you can still acces.

Then I tried controlling the domain.com via users but that just blocks the html from being accessed without a login but direct links to the repo still worked.

So, the actual question: is there a way to have access to direct links such as domain.com/svn/repo require a login to view and how?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set up access control in SVN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81361/how-do-i-set-up-access-control-in-svn)

Comment: Hey, @SiddharthKaul I know it has been a while, but didn't want to leave this open like this. The question you referred to was securing it based on accounts and what I was looking for was securing it in terms of SSL and just ensuring that it required any type of login.